# Cannot bind Decimal property to view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a property in my Model. When I submit my form I received the below error.

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Array'.**

I am using MVC 5

```
public class PaymentInformationModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Payment Amount")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the {0}")]
    [MaxLength(9)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
    [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
}
```

What is wrong. I am entering normal number like 123.34.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PaymentInformationModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@model PaymentInformationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "Form1", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Payment Information</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PaymentAmount, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-10" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">PAY</button>
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of view and controller?

Comment: Just a guess, but does it have to do with your `MaxLengthAttribute`?

Comment: Apart from all this, you are using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679307(v=vs.110).aspx) of `RangeAttribute` class. I think you need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `MaxLength` attribute, which does not work with decimal data types. I am not sure if `RegularExpression` attribute works either, but I did not verify that.

Try removing these two attributes and see if your code is working now. If it does - you might need to think of a way to use other attributes, that work correctly with decimal types (and `Range` validator seems a good candidate for that).

Just to see if `MaxLength` can be the issue, I looked at [.NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs,54). Here is a relevant part of code from `IsValid` method from `MaxLengthAttribute` with my comments:

```
var str = value as string;   // Your type is decimal so str is null after this line
if (str != null) {
    length = str.Length;  // <- This statement is not executed
}
else {
    // Next line is where you must be receiving an exception:
    length = ((Array)value).Length;
}
```

Comment: @maxspan Then you will need to find a way how to implement your validation using other attributes. For `Range` try using other overload of attribute, like @Rohit416 mentioned in comment under your question

Comment: Yes I have used @Rohit416 trick. Dont know why he removed his comment

Comment: Oh, I should have kept it there, I thought it was not relevant could mislead because @dotnetom explained this well. Also i was not aware it was advised to be used. Besides I am posting that again for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is Maxlength

```
public class PaymentInformationModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Payment Amount")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the {0}")]
        //[MaxLength(9)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
        [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
        public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

works fine for me.